# display number of posts by category Shortcode

Tags: categories, shortcode

I have this code for show count of posts by category.

If I visit category sports, show in header 34 articles. If I visit Nutrition Category show in header 12 articles.

But this code is wrong, anyone know why?

```
add_shortcode('catcount', 'wp_get_cat_postcount');
function wp_get_cat_postcount($id) {
    $cat= get_the_category();
    echo '<span class="catcount">'. $cat[0]->count .' ARTÍCULOS</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the code is wrong, because there are a lot of errors in it:

1. Shortcodes should return its results and they shouldn't print anything.
2. Shortcode callback takes an array of attributes as first param and not an ID.
3. You don't do anything with the parameter of your shortcode callback.
4. You don't pass any ID to get_the_category, so it will return array of categories for current post.
5. You don't check if there is any category assigned (get_the_category can return empty array).

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_category()` gets the categories assigned to the 'current post', so there's several reasons this might not work in your case.

Firstly, the 'current post' isn't necessarily definitively set when you're using it outside The Loop.

Secondly, if the 'current post' (which is *probably* the first post on the current archive page) has multiple categories, then there's no guarantee that its first category (`$cat[0]`) will be the same category as the archive you're viewing.

If you want to get the number of posts in the category whose archive you're currently viewing, then use `get_queried_object()` to get that category:

```
function wpse_330091_get_cat_postcount() {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_queried_object();

        return '<span class="catcount">' . $cat->count . ' ARTÍCULOS</span>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'catcount', 'wpse_330091_get_cat_postcount' );
```

Also note:

- I've checked `is_category()` first, so that we know for sure that the queried object will be a category.
- Shortcodes need to `return` their output, not `echo`.
- `wp_` is a prefix used by WordPress, you should use your own prefix to avoid conflicts.